# Angular get remote Image URL in base64 format

Tags: javascript, angular, base64

I have a function that converts a image to base64 and returns the value.

In .ts file:--

```
async getBase64ImageFromUrl(imageUrl) {
  const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
  var res = await fetch(proxyurl+imageUrl);
  var blob = await res.blob();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      // console.log(reader.result); /// getting the base64 image URL here.
      resolve(reader.result);
      return;
    }, false);

    reader.onerror = () => {
      return reject(this);
    };
  
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  })
}
```

I wanted to get the value in in the HTML, I know I am doing something wrong

```
<img class="w-100" [src]="getBase64ImageFromUrl('https://dam.dev.catalog.1worldsync.com/im/img/GCP-5129882489061376')"/>
```

I know I am doing it wrong, wanted to know the right way to do this.

Comment: I think you can use async pipe here to get an actual value
[src]="getBase64ImageFromUrl('https://dam.dev.catalog.1worldsync.com/im/img/GCP-5129882489061376') | async"

Answer (score -1):

It's not Angular specific.

In general, you need to prepend the base64 string with `data:image/png;base64` if it was a `png` image.

```html
<img src="data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>" />
```

## Example:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Check these for more info:

- [Data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)
- [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

Comment: I know how to add base64 url to src, but I am already the value in that format in the line console.log(reader.result); but due to promise it is not rendering. I need help in the Angular part.

Comment: @TRIKONINFOSYSTEMS can you please try removing the `return` from inside the promise?